# Which Greek letter is commonly used to represent a count?

Tags: notation

Which Greek letter is commonly used to represent a count? For example, the Greek letter sigma ($\Sigma$) is commonly used to represent a sum.

Comment: What do you mean by "a count"?

Comment: The Latin letter $N$ (which is also capital Greek nu) is often used

Comment: “($\Sigma$) is commonly used to represent a sum” — Not nearly as much as $S$

Comment: Because Euler studied Greek.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While your "count" is quite vague, here is a possibility:

The count of elements in a set:

[What symbol gives the count of elements in a set?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2619920/what-symbol-gives-the-count-of-elements-in-a-set/2619939)

The latin letter *N* is, as pointed out in the comments, also sometimes used.